# angular mat table async render the data

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, angular-material, angular-material-table

i have a performance issue with angular matTable .
when it has a lot of data to render, it takes a lot of time to do so.
is there any way to render the table asynchronously? so each row will be render when it can?

Comment: What are you rendering in each row? How many rows? Are you using paging? Without these details there’s not much we can do to help

Comment: im rendering data with 10-20 columns and 1000 or so rows.
i dont know what paging is.

Comment: Most probably the amount of data is your problem. 1,000 rows is a lot for any browser to render. See here what paging is: https://v12.material.angular.io/components/table/examples#table-http